# What does "Post post = db.posts.Find(Id)" mean in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

What does `Post post = db.posts.Find(Id)` mean in ASP.NET MVC?

I am getting an error on "Posts": undefined. Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult ShowImage(int id)
{
    VirtualSpeechTherapistEntities db = new VirtualSpeechTherapistEntities();

    Post post = db.Posts.Find(id); // <- ERROR

    LetterInfo letterInfo = new LetterInfo();
    letterInfo.Letter_ID  = post.Letter_ID;
    letterInfo.Letter_Pic = post.image_url;

    //set all other information you required
    return View("TherapyLetter", letterInfo);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 3):

Possibly, the `Find` method is Entity Framework's method Find. The `db.Posts` returns a `DbSet<Post>` (I suppose that `Post` is the class that represents a post) and using `Find` you try to find a post with the id you pass there.

For further information on this, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx) and especially in section, *Finding an entity by primary key*.

Comment: I tried to write some query in post class but I didn't allow me to do so..getting an error on "var""and "where"

Comment: @zeifi Hi, it's quite difficult to help you providing me such a vague information. Please post your relevant code in your question, pointing where is the problem you met and specify as clear as you can what you are trying to do. Thanks :)

Comment: I was following some blog in which they use post but didn't define what is that and I thought it is some mvc's attribute/property but the link you posted helps me a lot . problem solved. thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)